# How can I return the uncommon characters between two separate strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I've been working on a coding challenge to return the uncommon characters between two separate strings. However I haven't had much luck in figuring it out. I've tried a number of methods that I have found when googling, none have quite worked. I did however come across a [hash mapping](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concatenated-string-uncommon-characters-two-strings/) method but the examples only included C++, Python, C — seeing as Ruby is my first programming language it's been difficult trying to translate such a complex challenge without making mistakes.

I'm not in any rush to figure this coding challenge out and would rather appreciate getting some feedback on what everyone else thinks may be worth me reading into in order to approach this question successfully.

Here is my code currently, please don't think much of it, I know it's far off from what it should be:

```
# Find concatenated string  
# with uncommon characters of given strings
def solve(a,b)
   res = "" # result  
    map = {} 
  
# store all characters of b in map
  [a,b].each.map{| character, element | for characters(1..26) << element[+1]
 }
# Find characters of a that are not 
# present in b and append to result
    
# Find characters of b that are not  
# present in a
    
    return res
end
```

Here is an example test case of what I'm trying to do, [click here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a262cfb8f27f217f700000b/train/ruby) for link to Kata challenge:

```
solve("xyab","xzca") = "ybzc" 
--The first string has 'yb' which is not in the second string. 
--The second string has 'zc' which is not in the first string.
```

Comment: Looks like the link to Kata is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed now!

Comment: A bit of advice for you -- Please put the actual problem at the top of your post. You're asking us to read two long paragraphs of background story, some failing code and an external link, before actually explaining *what is the problem you're trying to solve*? You could have written all four of the example test cases (e.g. `Test.assert_equals(solve("xyab","xzca"),"ybzc")`) right at the top of your question.

Comment: If I had done that someone else would have probably complained that I haven't put in any work to actually find an answer and downvoted my question before even reading  —  thanks for your point though, I'll bear that in mind next time.

Comment: Absolutely it's good to provide some "effort" alongside the question, especially your code sample. But nobody can make any sense of what's right/wrong about the code until after they've read the problem being solved -- so why is the problem right at the bottom? I think that advice applies to most "long messages" you might send (e.g. emails), not merely StackOverflow questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd treat strings as [arrays of characters](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-chars). You can easily find differences between arrays:

```
def solve(a, b)
  first_array = a.chars
  second_array = b.chars
  ((first_array - second_array) + (second_array - first_array)).uniq.join
end
```

Another approach is to use [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

```
require 'set'

def solve(a, b)
  (b.chars.to_set ^ a.chars.to_set).to_a.join
end
```

*UPD* `uniq` was added to the first approach as @3limin4t0r suggested.

Comment: Thanks @Yakov, I particularly like the .to_set method you used in the second example, very clean

Comment: @KobbyAdarkwa Although the set version might work. The description of [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is: *"Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates."* and [`to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-to_a) repeats *"Converts the set to an array. The order of elements is uncertain."* I'm normally a large fan of sets, but the array version might be better suited for this specific question.

Comment: Worth noting is that the first code block does not remove duplicates in the same string. If `a = "aaabbcc"` and `b = "bcddee"` the output will be `"aaaddee"`. So ideally you want to call `uniq` before `join`ing the characters back together.

Comment: @3limin4t0r It depends on task constraints but you are right, thanks. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the [answer of Yakov](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63958024/3982562) instead of adding the two differences together you could also subtract the intersection from the union between the two. (See [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference))

```
def solve(a, b)
 a = a.chars
 b = b.chars

 ((a | b) - (a & b)).join
end
```

Both the union method [`|`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) and intersection method [`&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-26) remove duplicates so there is no need to call `uniq` before `join`ing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that does not convert the strings to arrays of characters.

```
def non_common_chars(str1, str2)
  g = str1.each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = 1 }
  str2.each_char.with_object(g) do |c,h|
    if h.key?(c)
      h.delete(c) if h[c] == 1
    else
      h[c] = 2
    end
  end.keys.join
end
```

```
non_common_chars("abc-defaa", "abcm.nopp")
  #=> "-defm.nop"
```

If desired, the hash `g` could be factored out.

The steps are as follows.

```
str1 = "abc-defaa"
str2 = "abcm.nopp"

g = str1.each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = 1 }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "-"=>1, "d"=>1, "e"=>1, "f"=>1}
```

The keys of `g` comprise the unique characters in `str1`

```
e0 = str2.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "abcm.nopp":each_char> 
e1 = e0.with_object(g)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "abcm.nopp":each_char>:with_object(
  #     {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "-"=>1, "d"=>1, "e"=>1, "f"=>1})> 

h = e1.each do |c,h|
      if h.key?(c)
        h.delete(c) if h[c] == 1
      else
        h[c] = 2
      end
    end
  #=> {"-"=>1, "d"=>1, "e"=>1, "f"=>1, "m"=>2, "."=>2, "n"=>2,
  #    "o"=>2, "p"=>2}
```

The keys of `h` are now the unique characters in `str1` that are not in `str2` and unique characters in `str2` that are not in `str1`. Just two more steps:

```
a = h.keys
  #=> ["-", "d", "e", "f", "m", ".", "n", "o", "p"] 
a.join
  #=>"-defm.nop"
```

Comment: Although this works with simple strings, be careful with strings containing a backslash, `^` or `-`. If `str2 = "a-z"` it will delete all characters from "a" to "z" from `str1`. Ideally you want to escape these 3 special characters. `str1.delete(str2.gsub(/[-\\^]/, '\\\\\\0'))` the same applies for the other deletion.

Comment: @3limin4t0r's comment refers to my original answer, which was `def non_common_chars(str1, str2); (str1.delete(str2) + str2.delete(str1)).each_char.uniq.join; end`. The comment was instructive and deserves consideration.